# $\textbf{y} + U \leq V$ if and only if $\textbf{y} \in U$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ and $U \leq V$, $\textbf{y} \in V$, and $\textbf{y}+U = \{\textbf{y}+\textbf{u}| \textbf{u} \in U\}$. Prove that $\textbf{y} + U \leq V$ if and only if $\textbf{y} \in U$.

By $\leq$, I mean it is a subspace.

Proof:
($\Leftarrow$) Let $\textbf{y}\in U$. Since $U \leq V$, $\textbf{y}+U \leq V$.

($\Rightarrow$) Let $\textbf{y} + U \leq V$.

CLAIM: $\textbf{y} + U = U$

This is what I'm planning to do:
We first show that $U \leq \textbf{y} + U$. Then, we show  $\textbf{y} + U \leq U$. Thus, $U = \textbf{y} + U$. Therefore, $\textbf{y} \in U$.

Is it right?

Comment: By $\le$ do you mean $\subseteq$ ?

Comment: What I mean is subspace

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some problems about your proof of $\Leftarrow$, you didn't actually justify why $U \leq V \implies \textbf{y}+U \leq V$. In general, to show $A \leq B$, you do really have to show $A \subseteq B$ and $A$ is closed under linear combinations. But you wrote nothing about these two conditions. In fact, $\textbf{y} + U$ is not even a subspace of $V$ if $\textbf{y} \notin U$.

Here is my answer. In this case, To show $\Leftarrow$, it suffices to show $\textbf{y} \in U \implies \textbf{y} + U = U$:

Suppose $\textbf{y} \in U$. ($\subseteq$) Given any $\textbf{x} \in \textbf{y} + U$, there is $\textbf{u} \in U$ such that $\textbf{y}+\textbf{u}=\textbf{x}$. Since $U$ is closed under addition, $\textbf{x} \in U$. ($\supseteq$) Given any $\textbf{u} \in U$, take $\textbf{v} = \textbf{u} - \textbf{y}$. Then $\textbf{v} \in U$ and $\textbf{v} + \textbf{y} = \textbf{u}$. So that $\textbf{u} \in \textbf{y} + U$.

Now we give a proof to the original problem:

$\Leftarrow$: Suppose $\textbf{y} \in U$. Then $\textbf{y}+U = U \leq V$.

$\Rightarrow$: Suppose $\textbf{y} + U  \leq V$. Since $\textbf{0} \in U$, $\textbf{y} = \textbf{y}+ \textbf{0} \in \textbf{y} + U$. Since $\textbf{y} + U$ forms a subspace of $V$, it is closed under scalar multiplication. So that $2 \textbf{y} = \textbf{y}+ \textbf{y}\in  \textbf{y} + U$. Thus $\textbf{y} \in U$.